# Calling loader show/hide function in magento 2 js template

Tags: magento2, ajax

I have been creating a custom component to load cart items in **Magento 2 modal widget**. I have to show a loader only in a custom **div** tag. Here is the code of my custom js component.

```
 define([
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'mage/url',
        'mage/storage',
    ], function (ko, Component, urlBuilder, storage) {
        'use strict';
        var self = this;
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'RLTSquare_PartialCheckout/cart'
            },

            //models are defined here
            cartItemsList: ko.observableArray(),
            shouldShowLoader: ko.observable(false),

            initialize: function () {
                self = this;
                this._super();
                this.loadList();
            },
            loadList: function () {
                self.shouldShowLoader(true);
                var serviceUrl = urlBuilder.build('rltsquare_partialcheckout/cart/get');
                return storage.post(
                    serviceUrl, ''
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        self.cartItemsList.removeAll();
                        var list = response;
                        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                            self.cartItemsList.push(list[i]);
                        }
                        self.shouldShowLoader(false);
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        self.shouldShowLoader(false);
                        alert(response);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there a way I can get magento 2 loader in my **.html** file or **.js** file?
I have already bound it to my .html template as:

```
<div data-role="loader" data-bind="visible: shouldShowLoader" class="loading-mask" style="position: absolute;">
    <div class="loader">
        <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/m2-2.2/pub/static/version1513844156/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/loader-1.gif" alt="Loading..." style="position: absolute;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I already went through [mage/loader](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_loader.html) component defined in M2 but could not find its usage properly.

Is there a way I can get the absolute url of this image in js component?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use following code for show/hide loader

**Show loader :**  `jQuery('body').loader('show');`

**Hide Loader :** `jQuery('body').loader('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento loader, read here for more detail:
https://mrvts.wordpress.com/2018/05/30/how-to-use-magento-2-loader-widget/

Magento loader is: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/web/mage/loader.js

You can take a look this file to know more detail function in it.